# Matlab plot in real time

Tags: matlab

I just want to know how can I modify this code to be a real-time plot. I mean, those red-cross appears on my graph progressively rather than all of them show up at the same time. sorry for my bad English

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rEysS.png

Comment: For your future questions, please don't post code as images but rather paste the actual code from your favorite editor. Thanks!